# Reason for rounded fitting at the top end of Allihn Condenser

Tags: equipment, distillation

[image]

I am purchasing an essential oil distillation setup. The Allihn Condenser at the top end, and the attached glassware, are rounded. It is supposedly 24/40. I have never seen this. If one of them broke, I would have a hard time finding a replacement because of the strange shape. Thus, I am wondering if there is a good reason for the shape, or if I should ask the manufacturer to give me a normally-shaped 24/40 connection.

Thank you for sharing your thoughts, in advance.

Comment: The metal clip (bottom right of the picture next to the adjustable clamp arm) will hold it in place.

Comment: That's a _spherical joint._ It's standardized laboratory glassware. However, NS 24/40 is not a nominal size for spherical joints. It's probably a KS 35/20 or so.